# Cannot find symbol

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have not been able to get my methods working, as when I import classes from the same package it gives me an error. When I put them in the same package it gives me an error of "cannot find symbol", referring to the class/method I am trying to use in the second one. Like here for example, I can use variables from the other classes but it throws an error whenever I use a method. I have seen similar problems but none of them have helped me so far.

**1st class:**

```
package main;

/**
*
* @author Darias
*/
public class Main {

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ball p;
        p = new ball();
        System.out.println("the ball weighs" +p.getlength);
    }

}
```

**2nd class:**

```
package main;

public class ball {

    float length;
    float weight;
    public ball()
    {
        length = 100;
        weight = 250;
    }
    public ball(float length, float peso)
    {
        this.length = length;
        this.weight = weight;
    }
    public float getlength()
    {
        return length;
    }
    public float getweight()
    {
        return weight;
    }
    public void kickball()
    {
        System.out.println("you kicked the ball");
    }
    public void atraparPelota()
    {
        System.out.println("you caught the ball");
    }

}
```

Note: it's properly indented in the program, here I was just having trouble passing it to text

Comment: `p.getlength` should be `p.getlength()` in `System.out.println("the ball weighs" +p.getlength);`

Comment: 'When I import classes from the same package it gives me an error'. You don't have to import classes from the same package. Netbeans has really nothing to do with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getlength` is a function  so use this way: `"the ball weighs" +p.getlength()`
and please use visibility  syntax and be object oriented: `private, protected etc.`

```
public class Ball {

   private float length;
   private float weight;
   public Ball()
   {
     this.length = 100;
     this.weight = 250;
   }
   public Ball(float length, float peso)
   {
      this.length = length;
      this.weight = weight;
   }
   public float getLength()
   {
      return length;
   }
   public float getWeight()
   {
     return weight;
   }
   public void kickBall()
   {
     System.out.println("you kicked the ball");
   }
   public void atraparPelota()
   {
     System.out.println("you caught the ball");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the parentheses after `p.getlength` in `Main`.

```
System.out.println("the ball weighs" +p.getlength());
```